# Problem in Riemann integral

Tags: riemann-integration

Show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{10}\frac{n[11-x]}{1+n^2x^2}dx=11\frac{\pi}{2}$$ $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer function

here $[11-x]$ is discontinuous at $0,1,2,..,10$ so i divide this integration and after solve i don't get this answer. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Substitute $nx = t$

Comment: I'm getting $10\pi / 2$